# How to initiate Jquery events after .less finish to parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, less

I'm using .less for my css. The problem I have is because Jquery runs before .less finish to parse the .less file, heights and widths aren't the corrects.

Now I set a setTimeout of 500 milisenconds to "wait", is there any callback funcition on .less to start jquery stuff?

Thanks

```
jQuery(function($){
   var m = $('.my-class').height();
   var wh = $(window).height();

   if(wh > m){
      $('.my-class').addClass('.new-class').height(wh - 300);
   }
});
```

I have to do this, to get it working:

```
jQuery(function($){
   var m = $('.my-class').height();
   var wh = $(window).height();

   setTimeout(function(){
      if(wh > m){
         $('.my-class').addClass('.new-class').height(wh - 300);
      }
   }, 500);
});
```

Comment: i don't know .less but you tried with a $(window).load ?

Comment: Please post an example.  If you have all the elements in the head section, resources are loaded sequentially, so this should not be a problem.

Comment: Make sure `async` is set to `false` in your less options. Then any js you put after less.js should wait until the .less files are parsed.

Comment: @ericponto, where do I set those settings in .less?

Comment: Check out the client side usage info in the docs: http://lesscss.org/#usage

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery .ready() event on whatever .less is executing on most likely. So if you have a paragraph that .less is styling, you can do something like `$("p").ready(function() { //do something });`. If that doesn't work, you can always try the .resize() event as well since the element should be resized when less is done styling it. For example, you can do something like `$("p").resize(function() { //do something now that the size has changed });`

Documentation:

- http://api.jquery.com/ready/
- http://api.jquery.com/resize/